# Accessing Dynamic Form Arrays HTML/Bootstrap/Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to create a form that will allow a user to input multiple loans.  The form has one row with inputs for balance, interest rate and minimum payment, and clicking the +/- button will allow them to add or remove rows.  Visually, the functionality SEEMS ok, but I am trying to test by printing out the array and it is failing.

This is in the early stages, so I am just trying to make sure the variables are being created and can be accessed correctly before I move on to the page functionality.  I am rusty with web development so these may not be the best methods.  Any input would be much appreciated.

This is my form:

```
<form id="loanform" role="form" autocomplete="off" method="post" onsubmit="hello()">
                <div class="entry input-group col-xs-3">How much extra money can you pay per month?
                    <input class="form-control" name="extra" type="text" placeholder="Extra/month" />
                </div>
                <br>
                <div class="entry input-group col-xs-9">
                    <div class="col-xs-3">
                        <input class="form-control" name="balances['+current+']" id="balances'+current+'" type="text" placeholder="Loan Balance" required="required" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-3">
                        <input class="form-control" name="rates['+current+']" id="rates'+current+'" type="text" placeholder="Interest Rate" required="required" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-3">
                        <input class="form-control" name="payments['+current+']" id="payments'+current+'" type="text" placeholder="Minimum Payment" required="required" />
                    </div> <span class="input-group-btn col-xs-1">
                                   <button class="btn btn-success btn-add" type="button">
                                           <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>

                    </button>
                    </span>
                </div>
        </div>
        <div class="input-group-btn">
            <div class="col-xs-5">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        </form>
```

Here is the Javascript for the creation of new inputs:

```
$(function () {
$(document).on('click', '.btn-add', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var controlForm = $('.controls form:first'),
        currentEntry = $(this).parents('.entry:first'),
        newEntry = $(currentEntry.clone()).appendTo(controlForm);

    newEntry.find('input').val('');
    controlForm.find('.entry:not(:last) .btn-add')
        .removeClass('btn-add').addClass('btn-remove')
        .removeClass('btn-success').addClass('btn-danger')
        .html('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span>');
}).on('click', '.btn-remove', function (e) {
    $(this).parents('.entry:first').remove();

    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
});
```

});

And this is the function I'm calling onsubmit:

```
function hello() {
alert("Hello has been called");
var bal = document.getElementById('balances0').value;
alert(bal);
alert("function over");
```

}

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Afterbyrner/u55szysh/

Answer (score 1):

There are some problems in your code:

1. `hello` is not a global method. You could add it like this `window.hello = hello;` then it would be accessible. But I'd recommend to use `$(...).submit(...)`
2. `id="balances'+current+'"` is not valid in HTML. That won't be executed.
3. I would add classes to each input field and `data-index` for easier accessing.
4. Storing your form in DOM is not good because you can't keep the index clean. It would be better to create your form in JS as an array and update this array at each +/- click.
   What I mean is that if for example you added two rows then the second row will have `data-index=1` and if you remove the DOM element before with index 0 and re-add a row then you don't have index 0 in your list.

You can find the updated jsFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/awolf2904/u55szysh/1/).

I'll improve the code to show what I mean with the array approach later.

---

**Update 08.03.2015**

Please find the updated code in this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/awolf2904/u55szysh/8/) and below.

I've added the following code:

- Keep track of the form elements in an array
- Stored the form element for each row as a template in a `<script type="text/template"/>` tag.
- Added the index of the array item to the `name` attribute of each form input
- Changed access to the form data inside of `$.submit(...)` to `$.serializeArray()`
- Added focus change to the new input row after adding the new row.

I think that should be a good starting point for your calculation app now.

```js
$(function() {
    //console.log($('#template_add_form'));
    var clone = function(tmpl) {
            return $((tmpl.clone()).html())
        },
        $template = $('#template_add_form'),
        formArray = [ clone($template) ], // init array with first row
        $formEntries = $('#entries');
    
    $(document).on('click', '.btn-add', function() {
        //console.log('clicked');
        formArray.push(clone($template));
        updateForm();
        // set focus to adding row = last element in array
        $(formArray).last()[0]
            .find('input')
            .first()
            .focus();
    });
    
    // remove not working yet
    
    $(document).on('click', '.btn-remove', function(evt) {
        var id;
        // iterate over formArray to find the currently clicked row
        $.each(formArray, function(index, row) {
            //console.log(index, row.has(evt.currentTarget).length);
            if ( row.has(evt.currentTarget).length == 1 ) {
                //console.log(row.has(evt.currentTarget));
                id = index; // click target in current row
                return false; // exit each loop
            }
        });
        
        //console.log('clicked', id);
        formArray.splice(id, 1);
        updateForm();
    });
    
    var updateForm = function() {
        // redraw form --> problem values are cleared!!
        //console.log(formArray);
        var lastIndex = formArray.length - 1,
            name; // stores current name of input
        
        $formEntries.empty(); // clear entries from DOM becaue we re-create them
        $.each(formArray, function(index, $input) {
            //console.log(index, $input);
            // update names of inputs and add index
            //console.log('inputs', $input.find('input'));
            $.each($input.find('input'), function(inputIndex, input) {
                name = $(input).attr('name').replace(/\d+/g, ''); // remove ids
                $(input).attr('name', name + index);
            });
            
            if (index < lastIndex) {
                // not last element --> change button to minus
                //console.log($input.find('.btn-add'));
                $input.find('.btn-add')
                     .removeClass('btn-add').addClass('btn-remove')
                     .removeClass('btn-success').addClass('btn-danger')
                     .html('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span>');
            }
            
            $formEntries.append($input);
        });
    };
    
    updateForm(); // first init. of form
    
    $('form#loanform').submit(function(evt) { 
        evt.preventDefault();
        var fields = $(this).serializeArray();
        $.each(fields, function(index, field) {
            //console.log(field.name);
            if ( field.name == 'extra' ) {
                console.log('extra', field.name, field.value);
            }
            if ( field.name.contains('balance') ) 
            {   // field.name contains balance
                console.log('balance', field.name, field.value);
                // now you can do your calculation
            }
            if ( field.name.contains('rate') )
            {   // field.name contains balance
                console.log('rate', field.name, field.value);
                // now you can do your calculation
            }
            if ( field.name.contains('payment') )
            {   // field.name contains balance
                console.log('payment', field.name, field.value);
                // now you can do your calculation
            }
        });
    });
});
```

```css
body {
    .entry:not(:first-of-type) {
        margin-top: 10px;
    }
    .glyphicon {
        font-size: 12px;
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script id="template_add_form" type="text/template">
    <div class = "entry input-group col-xs-9">
        <div class = "col-xs-3">
            <input class = "form-control" name="balance" type = "text" 
                   placeholder = "Loan Balance" required = "required"/>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-3">
            <input class="form-control" name="rate" type="text" placeholder="Interest Rate" required="required" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-3">
            <input class="form-control" name="payment" type="text" placeholder="Minimum Payment" required="required"/>
        </div> 
        <span class="input-group-btn col-xs-1">
            <button class="btn btn-success btn-add" type="button">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span >
            </button>
        </span>
    </div>
</script>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="control-group" id="fields">
            <label class="control-label" for="field1">
                 <h3>Enter your loans below</h3>

            </label>
            <div class="controls">
                <form id="loanform" role="form" autocomplete="off" method="post">
                    <div class="entry input-group col-xs-3">How much extra money can you pay per month?
                        <input class="form-control" name="extra" type="text" placeholder="Extra/month" />
                    </div>
                    <br>
                    <div id="entries"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="input-group-btn">
                <div class="col-xs-5">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            </form>
            <br> <small>Press <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus gs"></span> to add another loan</small>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks!  The "+current+" was something I found on another StackOverflow thread.  I didn't have much confidence in it because I'd never seen it before, but I figured it was worth a shot.  My first goal was to get the dynamic inputs working because I wont know how many loans someone is inputting.  The "hello" method is mostly there for testing.  Ultimately it will be replaced with a bunch of sorting and math, but I needed something to run onsubmit and see if I'm successfully passing all of my arrays, which I'm clearly not.  I figured I'd focus on balances first and replicate it for the other two